# To what extent can you be forgiven?

Tags: sin, nature-of-god, confession

Is it really true that no matter what you do, you can still be saved, go to heaven, if you confess and repent? And, what if, due to crappy circumstances, you've become detached, and lost the ability (or maybe forgotten how) to believe/hope/have faith in things? Will He be understanding?

Comment: Hi and welcome to our community. Understandings of how complete forgiveness is vary by denomination (though I don't think any will suggest that anyone is too far gone to surpass the ability of Christ's forgiveness). However, it would be helpful if you told us what exactly you are looking to learn here. This question is quite broad. Generally we suggest that questions be scoped to a particular denomination or set of beliefs. The reason for this is that Christianity rarely has a single reasonable answer. This narrowing allows us to deal in facts rather than speculation.

Comment: Closed pending the address of the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1Jn 1:9  If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins, and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness.
>
> Mat 18:21  Then came Peter to him, and said, Lord, how oft shall my brother sin against me, and I forgive him? till seven times?
> Mat 18:22  Jesus saith unto him, I say not unto thee, Until seven times: but, Until seventy times seven.
>
> Jer 3:12  Go and proclaim these words toward the north, and say, Return, thou backsliding Israel, saith the LORD; and I will not cause mine anger to fall upon you: for I am merciful, saith the LORD, and I will not keep anger for ever.
>
> Php 2:13  For it is God which worketh in you both to will and to do of his good pleasure.

From a purely Biblical perspective, based on the Scripture quoted above and the teachings of a Word of Faith church.
Yes the Lord will forgive and take anyone back as long as they repent. 70x7 was the equivalent of infinity during days of Jesus on the earth. When God required an infinite amount of daily forgiveness from His people He naturally requires such of Himself also. Any normal sin or mistake can be corrected with repentance. The Lord is understanding and merciful to faults and backslides and will help anyone do and want to do the things which please Him. All one must do is start with repentance make Jesus the personal King and Friend of their life, then read the Bible and go to church.

Comment: From 1 Chronicles 29:7 (ISV):  "They presented 5,000 gold talents and 10,000 gold darics for the work of the Temple of God, 10,000 silver talents, 18,000 bronze talents, and 100,000 iron talents."  70x7 = 490.

Comment: @Chelonian different cultures have described infinity in different ways. 70x7 is not 490 in this context. http://biblehub.com/matthew/18-22.htm

Comment: Thank you. From what I remember of 70x7, I remember reading that someone didn't pay his brother back and the brother asked God how many times he should forgive is brother, and that's when God said 70x7 (correct me if I'm wrong) - I haven't read the whole Bible _yet_, but this whole 70x7 thing - is that applied to everything? It seems like a bit of an arbitrary number. Does that mean that if someone needs to be forgiven for 495 times, it won't happen? Or is that number a basis for how much us humans must forgive each other?

Comment: @jason0550 70x7 is closer to infinity than 495. if you need forgivness a million times over the Lord will still forgive you.

Comment: @caseyr547 thank you. I'm not sure I follow, though. Are you implying that the negative side of 0 is infinity? (I say this because 70x7 is less that 495)

Comment: @jason0550 well i mean that 70x7 doesn't equate to 490. this isn't normal math. It represents an ideal which is infinite because God's mercies are renewed every time we repent and every time the sun sets. Each day and each time we repent the count starts over again. And though it is possible to sin 490 times in a day or even a minute (this would be very difficult though) as long as we repent the Lord hears our prayers and forgives us.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clearing it up for me. And thanks for the answer, @caseyr547.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering from a Catholic perspective:

> Is it really true that no matter what you do, you can still be saved,
>   go to heaven, if you confess and repent?

Yes.

> And, what if, due to crappy circumstances, you've become detached, and
>   lost the ability (or maybe forgotten how) to believe/hope/have faith
>   in things? Will He be understanding?

The Church will not tell you what God will and will not do, except in cases where this has been revealed to the Church.

So, the church will say, because it was revealed to Her, that it has the power to forgive sins, and that God will honor the request of the priest who does so.

However, the church cannot say what will happen to someone who does not confess through his own fault or through no fault of his own.

This is why the Church has **never** said that this or that person is in hell.

So yes, anyone can be saved; it is up to God. It is a sin however, to knowingly abstain from seeking grace through the Church because you believe that God will forgive you anyway, ie, wanting to be saved "on your own terms."

Comment: Could you point to your source for this?  Ideally, an answer from a Catholic perspective will point to the relevant catechism, papal encyclical or the like.

Comment: @JonEricson yea, I guess that would be good. I would have to go digging as it is nothing in one place I don't think. will try to amend.